# Считывается только часть ячеек excel interop, остальные null

Tags: c#, interop

При попытке считать все ячейки документа Excel с помощью библиотеки Interop, часть ячеек считывается корректно, часть(большая) не считывается вовсе, и в итоге отображается как null. Использование Text, Value2 результата не меняет.

```
var lastCell = excelworksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell);
            int lastColumn = (int)lastCell.Column;//!сохраним непосредственно требующееся в дальнейшем
            int lastRow = (int)lastCell.Row;
            string[,] list = new string[lastCell.Column, lastCell.Row]; // массив значений с листа равен по размеру листу
            for (int k = 0; k < (int)lastCell.Column; k++) //по всем колонкам
                for (int j = 0; j < (int)lastCell.Row; j++)
                { // по всем строкам
                    list[i, j] = (excelworksheet.Cells[j + 1, i + 1] as Excel.Range).Value;//считываем текст в строку

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сделать так:

```
        public DataModel GetDataFromExcelFile(string filePath, int startRow, int startColumn, int endColumn)
      {
        Excel.Workbook wb = null;
        Excel.Application excel = null;
        Excel.Worksheet xlSheets = null;

        try
        {
            excel = new Excel.Application();
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
            xlSheets = wb.ActiveSheet;

            Excel.Range range = xlSheets.UsedRange;
            int rowsCount = range.Rows.Count;

            var startCell = (Excel.Range)xlSheets.Cells[startRow, startColumn];
            var endCell = new object();
            endCell = (Excel.Range)xlSheets.Cells[rowsCount, endColumn];
            var writeRange = xlSheets.get_Range(startCell, endCell);
            var data = writeRange.get_Value();

            var dataModel = new DataModel
            {
                RowCount = rowsCount,
                Data = data
            };
            return dataModel;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            wb?.Close(false, filePath);

            if (xlSheets != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlSheets);
            if (excel != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
            if (wb != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb);
        }
      }
```